# Were there violence before July 3 and July 4 during the 1989 Tiananmen Square protests?

Tags: china

Were there violence before July 3 and July 4 during the 1989 Tiananmen Square protests? I heard the protests were peaceful, but I learned recently that there were a lot of soldiers who got injured, so I was wondering if outside of Beijing before July 3 and July 4, and if there were violent protest and soldiers injured before July 3 and July 4. I've read a lot of conflicting views and testimonies so I am trying to understand exactly what happened.

Here are some of them:

https://search.wikileaks.org/plusd/cables/89BEIJING18828_a.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chai_Ling

Footage from a documentary titled The Gate of Heavenly Peace shows viewers parts of an interview between Chai and reporter Philip Cunningham from May 28, 1989, a week prior to the Tiananmen Square Incident. In the footage, Chai makes the following statements:

> All along I've kept it to myself, because being Chinese I felt I
>   shouldn't bad-mouth the Chinese. But I can't help thinking sometimes –
>   and I might as well say it – you, the Chinese, you are not worth my
>   struggle! You are not worth my sacrifice!
>
> What we actually are hoping for is bloodshed, the moment when the
>   government is ready to brazenly butcher the people. Only when the
>   Square is awash with blood will the people of China open their eyes.
>   Only then will they really be united. But how can I explain any of
>   this to my fellow students?
>
> "And what is truly sad is that some students, and famous
>   well-connected people, are working hard to help the government, to
>   prevent it from taking such measures. For the sake of their selfish
>   interests and their private dealings they are trying to cause our
>   movement to disintegrate and get us out of the Square before the
>   government becomes so desperate that it takes action....
>
> Interviewer: "Are you going to stay in the Square yourself?
>
> Chai Ling: "No."
>
> Interviewer: "Why?"
>
> Chai Ling: "Because my situation is different. My name is on the
>   government's blacklist. I'm not going to be destroyed by this
>   government. I want to live. Anyway, that's how I feel about it. I
>   don't know if people will say I'm selfish. I believe that people have
>   to continue the work I have started. A democracy movement can't
>   succeed with only one person. I hope you don't report what I've just
>   said for the time being, okay?"

Something makes me wonder if people caused violence in Tiananmen Square, in Beijing or around Beijing before July 3 and July 4. However, because I don't have the timeline sorted out after reading the article on the protest on Wikipedia, I would like to ask the people here.

Comment: You probably mean June 3rd and 4th. PLA troops have being gathering near Beijing since May. Marshal law was declared on May 20th, military and police tried to move towards the square, but initially they didn't use much force and came upon roadblocks where some minor scuffles happened. They decided to retreat which only encouraged protestors.

Comment: The quote you highlight only mentions government violence.... While at it though, I would be highly surprised if some of the protests didn't include some people being violent. Not kill-loads-of-people like the Chinese Communist party violent though.

Comment: Too many assertions without evidence.  Too many " I wonder" statements.  Is this a push question?  I don't see any evidence in the sources provided to support the allegations made in this question.  The more I read this question, the more it seems to be an effort to shape/argue history than to investigate history.